# How-to convert csb to ccbi file on Windows?

Tags: cocos2d-x, csb

all!

I have some example files (csb) from Cocos2d Studio. 
I want to run them on cocos2d-xna framework, but it requires only compiled files (ccbi).
How can I compile or conver csb under Windows or run sprite from csb file :)

Thanks!

Comment: Cocoszudio sill generate the ccbi files when you publish. It requires a CCBReader component to load ccbi files. You should check if there's support at all for cocostudio in cocos2d-xna - since cocostudio is for official cocos2d-x framework and the xna part (no longer) part of the official framework you will need to rely on 3rd party ccbreader, if any.